# Magento 2 REST API Oauth signature invalid - working in Postman but not in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, magento2, node-red

I am trying to call a Magneto 2 REST API with Oauth authentication. The call works in Postman, but when I call the API from Node-Red it says: "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again."

Here is a sample of the script that I created to generate the authorization header:

```
//Variables required from the function calling this flow
var p_http_method = "GET";
var p_url = "https://watchguard24.co.za/rest/V1/modules/";

//Static variables for Magento authorization
const p_oauth_version = "1.0";
const p_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA256";
const p_nonce = "17TTbZZM0fi" //encodeURIComponent(uuid.v4()); //"35WpXRWuoQp" //uuid.v4();
const p_consumer_key = "wypklfmtf6m53b0rfclxikr2xibopftu";
const p_access_token = "umnmupjtpidzuzz47vuo5s2ianxmq7cf";
const p_consumer_secret = encodeURIComponent("fw17d1k3i70zldcy7xvuvtjjykrzw286");
const p_token_secret = encodeURIComponent("lroq3mg3vteogfisez7hu2zwbu7fmq2x");
const p_timestamp = 1668081726 //Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

//Combining OAuth parameters
const parameters = {
    oauth_consumer_key: p_consumer_key,
    oauth_nonce: p_nonce,
    oauth_signature_method: p_signature_method,
    oauth_timestamp: p_timestamp,
    oauth_version: p_oauth_version,
    oauth_token: p_access_token
}

//Ordering and encoding the variables
let ordered = {};
Object.keys(parameters).sort().forEach(function (key) {
    ordered[key] = parameters[key];
});

let encodedParameters = '';

for (var k in ordered) {
    const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(ordered[k]);
    const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(k);
    if (encodedParameters === '') {
        encodedParameters += encodeURIComponent(`${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`)
    }
    else {
        encodedParameters += encodeURIComponent(`&${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`);
    }
}

//Base signature string
const encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(p_url);

encodedParameters = encodeURIComponent(encodedParameters);

const signature_base_string = encodeURIComponent(`${p_http_method}&${encodedUrl}&${encodedParameters}`)

//Create the oauth signature
const signing_key = `${p_consumer_secret}&${p_token_secret}`

const oauth_signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", signing_key).update(signature_base_string).digest('base64');

//Encode oauth signature
const encoded_oauth_signature = encodeURIComponent(oauth_signature);

msg.headers = {
    "Authorization": 
        'OAuth oauth_consumer_key=' + p_consumer_key 
        + ',oauth_token=' + p_access_token 
        + ',oauth_signature_method=' + p_signature_method
        + ',oauth_timestamp=' + p_timestamp
        + ',oauth_nonce=' + p_nonce
        + ',oauth_signature=' + encoded_oauth_signature
        + ',oauth_version=' + p_oauth_version
}

return msg;
```

I then changed the parameters in the script to match those of Postman but I am not getting the same signature that Postman is generating.

Here is the Postman authorization header details:

```
OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key="wypklfmtf6m53b0rfclxikr2xibopftu",
oauth_token="d07jwep9s79srvy3dmjltlfafnpl9d1d",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
oauth_timestamp="1668081726",
oauth_nonce="17TTbZZM0fi",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="yktg8XIKp%2Fsjk2Wzr4Qk7Mxs6B7kY%2Fjx3040UvwHuY8%3D"
```

Here is the Node-Red (Node.js) authorization header generated:

```
OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key=wypklfmtf6m53b0rfclxikr2xibopftu,
oauth_token=d07jwep9s79srvy3dmjltlfafnpl9d1d,
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256,
oauth_timestamp=1668081726,
oauth_nonce=17TTbZZM0fi,
oauth_version=1.0,
oauth_signature=8GPa253AV9I%2FIGB9N2s2Urbg7Km%2FUcjhzM%2BeRjuEag4%3D
```

Can anyone please assist with any potential fixes for my script that the correct oauth signature is generated? I have followed the Magento 2 documentation (https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth/) regarding the signature generation. I then looked at the following guidance but I still get the same error: https://pandeysoni.medium.com/how-to-create-oauth-1-0a-signature-in-node-js-7d477dead170

I need to be able to generate the same oauth signature as Postman to successfully call the REST API's and not get an invalid signature error.